# HERE Maps: Invalid Client Authorization header, expecting signed request format

Tags: node.js, oauth, nestjs, here-api

I'm using a NestJS backend to perform calls to HERE Maps API.

What I try to achieve is to make a token request in a dedicated service like this:

```js
  @Injectable()
  export class HereMapsService {
  
    constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {
      this.getToken()
    }
  
    private getToken() {
      const consumerKey: string = this.configService.get('HERE_CONSUMER_KEY')
      const nonce: string = uuid()
      const timestamp: number = new Date().getTime() / 1000
      const signature: string = this.getSignature(nonce, timestamp, consumerKey)
      const headers = {
        'Authorization': `OAuth oauth_consumer_key="${consumerKey}",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="${timestamp}",oauth_nonce="${nonce}",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="${signature}"`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
  
      axios
        .post('https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token', 'grant_type=client_credentials', { headers })
        .then((result) => console.log(result))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    }
  
    private getSignature(nonce: string, timestamp: number, consumerKey: string): string {
      const consumerSecret: string = encodeURIComponent(this.configService.get('HERE_CONSUMER_SECRET')) + '&'
      const urlBaseString: string = encodeURIComponent(this.configService.get('HERE_BASE_URL') + '/oauth2/token')
      const signatureBaseString: string = encodeURIComponent(`grant_type=client_credentials&oauth_consumer_key=${consumerKey}&oauth_nonce=${nonce}&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256&oauth_timestamp=${timestamp}&oauth_version=1.0`)
      const finalString = `POST&${urlBaseString}&${signatureBaseString}`
  
      return crypto.createHmac('sha256', consumerSecret).update(finalString).digest('base64')
    }
  
  }
```

The response I get is:

> data: {
> errorId: 'ERROR-ec0c9a2c-2836-4a6b-ac8a-2b2aca74650a',
> httpStatus: 401,
> errorCode: 401202,
> message: 'Invalid Client Authorization header, expecting signed request format.',
> error: 'invalid_request',
> error_description: "**errorCode: '401202'. Invalid Client Authorization header, expecting signed request format.**"
> }

I guess the problem is located in my getSignature() method but I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I solved in in php curl, the request header needs to be in the following format:

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'oauth_consumer_key: '.urlencode($ACCESS_KEY_ID),
'oauth_nonce: '.urlencode($oauth_nonce),
'oauth_signature: '.urlencode($signature),
'oauth_signature_method: '.urlencode($oauth_signature_method),
'oauth_timestamp: '.urlencode($oauth_timestamp),
'oauth_version: '.urlencode($oauth_version),
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Authorization: OAuth  oauth_consumer_key="'.urlencode($ACCESS_KEY_ID).'",oauth_signature_method="'.urlencode($oauth_signature_method).'",oauth_timestamp="'.urlencode($oauth_timestamp).'",oauth_nonce="'.urlencode($oauth_nonce).'",oauth_version="'.urlencode($oauth_version).'",oauth_signature="'.urlencode($signature).'"'
),
```

And the post fields needs to be

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'grant_type=client_credentials',
```

Remember this is in php curl format.